# Nashorn vs browser script

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm using standalone js script in nashron and in browser. Why in nashron I'm getting

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "prototype" from undefined in <eval> at line number 21571
```

while in browser console script is working perfectly fine?
code i'm talking about is browserified https://github.com/jonkemp/inline-css
it's about 36k lines. This question is not about how to fix the code it's, rather about how to force nashorn to act like a browser interpreter

Comment: We do not have a magic bowl where we see your code ;) Please add it.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this solved my issue with js working in browser but not in Nashorn:

```
//load browser simulation environment
engine.eval("load('https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/attachment/11893/env.nashorn.1.2.js')");
```

I think it's an experimental solution to the browser problem. I found it here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8006183